# Bartlett Statistic

Tags: statistics, expected-value, jensen-inequality

> Let $w = \frac{s_2}{s_1}$, where $s_1 = \bar{x}$ (empirical mean), and $s_2 = \tilde{x}$ (geometric mean). Furthermore, Jensen's inequality states that $g(EV) \leq Eg(V)$ where $g$ is a convex function. Use this to prove that $0 < w \leq 1.$

So far I have been able to show that $$ \left[E\left(\tilde{X}^{1/n}\right)\right]^n \leq \left[E\left(\tilde{X}^{1/n}\right)\right]^n = E(\tilde{X})$$ by using Jensen's inequality, but not really sure how to progress further. Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Jensen's inequality,
\begin{align}
\ln(\bar{x})&=\ln\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{n}\right) \\
&\ge\sum_{i=1}^n  \frac{\ln(x_i)}{n} \\
&=\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^n x_i^{1/n}\right)=\ln(\tilde{x}).
\end{align}

Comment: $\ln(\tilde{x})$ looks almost identical to $\ln(\bar{x})$ on my screen